# A question about ellipse in different coordinate systems

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

As you know an ellipse equation is:

$(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$ in Cartesian system. (center of the system is at the center of the ellipse)

but also it is:

$r=a(1-e^2)/(1+e \cos (\theta))$ in polar system. ($r$ is distance to one of the focal points and $\theta$ is the angle between the arbitrary point, focal point and periapsis, i.e. if we name the point $Q$, the focal point $F$ and the periapsis $P$,  $\angle QFP$)

If we have $x = x_0 , y= y_0$ (we know the numerical values) and also the $e$, How can we find the $r_0$ and the $\theta_0$ for this specific point.

[image]

Comment: Can you say where the foci lie, in terms of $a$ and $b$? If so, for any point $P$ on the ellipse you can compute the distance $PF$ (with $F$ being a focus) and the angle between the $PF$ line and the major axis.

Comment: If you know the change-of-coordinate map and this is a local homeomorphism, then you should be able to sub-in and get an answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio . I added a picture to the question. Is it right to say that: $$L = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ $$W = arctan (y/x)$$ so we can use the cosine theorem to find $R$ or $r$ or FQ. and with this we can find the $\theta$. Is this right?

Comment: It's easier than that: $$r_0^2=(x_F-x_0)^2+y_0^2,\quad\theta_0=\pm\arccos{x_0-x_F\over r_0}.$$

Comment: @Aretino Please submit it as an answer so I can make it best answer. But before that, was what I said right or not?

Comment: Yes, you could it that way too.

Comment: The polar equation you’ve given places a focus at the origin, while the Cartesian equation has the origin at the ellipse’s center. They’re not quite the same thing since you need to apply a translation as well as the usual Cartesian-to-polar conversion to go from one to the other.